# cfhttp and cfhttpparam in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp, cfhttpparam

I have some XMl data, I want to use the XML data to be posted to a scheduler job so using cfhttp and cfhttpparam. But for reason after running this code I was not able to schedule a job in one of my site. Tried all the options with formfields, url and xml with no success. I was saving all my data into a xml variable using cfsavecontent and using that variable to pass into cfhttparam value. Not sure what Am I doing wrong here. Here is the below code

```
<cfsavecontent variable="getAllValues">
    <start_job job="/cf/ecs/get_ecspseg1_data">
        <params>
        <param name="1_script" value="#script#" />
        <param name="2_login" value="#login#"/>
        <param name="3_customer" value="#customer#"/>
        <param name="4_account" value="#account#"/>
        <param name="5_begdate" value="#begdate#"/>
        <param name="6_enddate" value="#enddate#"/>
        </params>
    </start_job>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfhttp url="http://ecs" port="4444" username="test" authType = "BASIC" password="testing*1" method="post">
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" name="testing" value="#ToString(getAllValues)#"/>
</cfhttp>
```

here is the updated code:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="getAllValues">
    <start_job job="/cf/smartecs/get_pseg1_data">
        <params>
        <param name="1_script" value="#script#" />
        <param name="2_login" value="#login#"/>
        <param name="3_customer" value="#customer#"/>
        <param name="4_account" value="#account#"/>
        <param name="5_begdate" value="#begdate#"/>
        <param name="6_enddate" value="#enddate#"/>
        </params>
    </start_job>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfhttp url="http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx" port="4444" username="myusername" authType = "BASIC" password="mypassword" method="post" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/octet-stream">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" name="testing"  value="#getAllValues#"/>
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Is the content within your CFSaveContent "CFOutputted"?  If not, the values you want won't be used. (You may also have to format the dates into the acceptable format or a default ODBC-like format may be used.)

Comment: Yes it is sourrounded with <cfoutput></cfoutput>

Comment: I am passing only the script name and rest all values are default or empty values

Comment: You may need to change "type" for your XML string to "body" and potentially set a "content-type" header. Maybe pass "content-length" too.  Depending on which version of ColdFusion (you didn't mention), if older, set header "TE" to "deflate;q=0".

Comment: Updated the code with suggested one. Still no good

Comment: Between tried with atom+xml for content-Type too

Comment: I would dump out values to ensure you are sending what you are expecting. I'd also report on the error message you are receiving from the API endpoint. (I've also had to pass `encoded="no"` in the body to prevent CF from encoding the XML.) What API/service are you posting to? There may be some unique requirements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182883/discussion-between-user3440782-and-james-moberg).

Comment: I removed your username and password from your code. Gotta watch out for that. Even though you're connecting to an internal machine, I'd recommend changing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a different Port number we need to even keep a / at the end of the URL. When I kept that / at the end of the URL it worked like a charm. ColdFusion will not accept : in the URL.

Comment: Where was the ":" in your original URL?

Comment: When using a port number you we will write the URL as http://10.xx.xx.xx:portNumber. as we had a Portnumber attribute we cannot include that in URL.

Comment: Gotcha. Didn't see that in the original question. Is your mapping for `ecs/` instead of `ecs`? Did you still have to use the `/` when using the IP address? I didn't think the `/` was required. :-/

Comment: Yes it is Required.. when the URL had a Port number we need to keep a / beside the URL.. it is weird though ..